# very basic short exact sequence problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow0$ and $f:A \rightarrow B, g: B \rightarrow C$, why is $C$ isomorphic to $B/A$? All I can show is that $C$ is isomorphic to $B/ Im (A)$. I've look up a few books but I still don't understand why $Im (A) = A$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, $B/A$ doesn't make sense unless $A\subseteq B$. However, since the second arrow is a monomorphism, you can identify $Im(A)$ with $A$ (they are isomorphic).

So you're exactly right that $B/Im(A)\cong C$, and you go one step further by considering $A$ and its monomorphic image as the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

This has confused me countless times. The example that always confuses me is this:$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}0 @>>>\mathbb{Z} @>{\cdot 2}>> \mathbb{Z} @>{\pi} >> \mathbb{Z}/2 @>>> 0 \\\end{CD}

So $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/2$! But this only makes sense because of the identification $\mathbb{Z} \simeq 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is injective (by exactness) we have $Im(A) \simeq A$, thus you're right, it's an acceptable abuse of language.